# Re-trying to fetch messages after an interval

Tags: spring-jms

The `DefaultMessageListenerContainer` (DMLC) polls for a message on the Q. If there is a message, it invokes the `onMessage` method of the Listener that has been configured. If the `onMessage` performs some operation such as a DB write, which fails due to some reason, we would like to rollback the transaction so that the message remains on the Q and is fetched in the next polling cycle.

However, we want DMLC to wait for a certain interval before attempting to re-poll after the failure of the transaction. This is so that we give the system some time to come out of the errorneous situation.

How can we achieve this?

Thanks,

Yash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do it in the `DMLC` - it's not supported by the JMS standard.

Some brokers, (e.g. ActiveMQ) can be configured to delay the redelivery.